# Does ARKit support iPhone SE?

Tags: ios, ios11, arkit, iphone-se

From https://developer.apple.com/arkit/:

> ARKit runs on the Apple A9, A10, and A11 processors.

From https://www.apple.com/iphone-se/specs/:

> A9 chip with 64‑bit architecture.

But from the [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html):

[image]

This says that iPhone SE is not compatible with ARKit. Could anybody clarify this for me?

**Update:** Apple updated the table. Now iPhone SE is showing as compatible with ARKit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, it depends only on the core chips. All iPhones with A9+ are compatible with ARKit. So the iPhone SE is also compatible.

I think Apple made a mistake in the table you attached.

Comment: Indeed, probably a mistake in the doc on Apple's part — developers have verified running ARKit on iPhone SE. [Filing a bug is always a good idea to be sure](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: As apple document says it starts with the A9 chip and yes iPhone SE.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html Please refer Table 1-1 it supported.

Comment: I can confirm that ARKit does work on the iPhone SE (I'm using it for ARKit development right now!).

Answer (score 0):

[Updated, So the iPhone SE is also compatible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO7T4.png)

[image]

Answer (score -4):

As apple document says it starts with the A9 chip and yes iPhone SE.
following device support the ARKit
iPhone SE
iPhone 6S
iPhone 6S Plus
iPhone 7
iPhone 7 Plus
iPad Pro (All three variants)
iPad New 2017
iPhone 8
iPhone X

Comment: Yes, it doesn't support iPhone SE, as the screenshot attached in above question, I also read the same so I answered on the basis of that.